# How to bind ItemTapped property of ListView in ViewModel for navigating detail page?

Tags: listview, mvvm, prism, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to figure out how to bind ItemTapped of ListView for navigating detail page with Prism.
I try with DelegateCommand but I have an error:

> Exception is: XamlParseException - Position 15:7. No Property of name ItemTapped found

View:

```
<ListView
  ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
  ItemTapped="{Binding ShowUserDetail}"
  RowHeight="65" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="15"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="11"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UsersViewModel : BindableBase
{

    ..... some bindable objects 

    INavigationService _navigationService;
    public DelegateCommand ShowUserDetail { get; set; }

    public UsersViewModel (INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        ShowUserDetail = new DelegateCommand(OnShowUserDetail);
    }

    public void OnShowUserDetail()
    {
        var par = new NavigationParameters();
        par.Add("user", SelectedUser);
        _navigationService.Navigate("UserDetail", par);
    }

    ....
```

When I bind this DelegateCommand to `<Button>` navigation works.
Probably this is not related to Prism but I can't find any example for using this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A Button has a Command property to bind to, while the ListView's ItemTapped is an event which needs an eventhandler. If you want to use binding, you'll have to use a behavior:

```
<ListView
  ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
  RowHeight="65" >
  <ListView.Behaviors>
    <b:EventToCommand EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ShowUserDetail}" />
  </ListView.Behaviors>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="15"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="11"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/180600/#Comment_180600

EDIT:
[EventToCommand](https://github.com/corradocavalli/Xamarin.Forms.Behaviors/blob/Version1.3/Xamarin.Behaviors/Library/EventToCommand.cs) is a behavior in [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Behaviors/).

Comment: Thank you for quick response

Comment: There is a documentation here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/

But, there is a nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Behaviors/ also.

Do I need to write custom method named EventToCommandBehavior or ?
I'm sorry, I'm relatively new in xamarin.

Comment: Looks like the package has EventToCommand class (without -Behavior). Updated the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Barts snippet somehow works too, but I really don't know how and what I have to implement. I suggest better explanation and some working code example.

I found solution that works.

After adding nuget package "xamarin forms behaviors" (in portable and all sub projects iOS, Android...), I added in ListView this:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">

    <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:BehaviorCollection>
            <b:EventToCommand EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ShowUserDetail}"/>
        </b:BehaviorCollection>
    </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
```

In header I set this line (mapped b to namespace):

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors"
```

One more thing, for iOS platform this must be placed in AppDelegate.cs / FinishedLaunching method (because of error exception, it's described here [xamarin-behaviors-with-xamarin-forms-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115447/xamarin-behaviors-with-xamarin-forms-ios))

```
Xamarin.Behaviors.Infrastructure.Init();
```

Now "ItemTapped" works correctly.